# "resolvectl dns" gives empty output

Tags: ubuntu, domain, vps, domain-name, resolv.conf

I do on my VPS with Ubuntu 22 server (new, clean setup):

```
root@vm905709:~# resolvectl dns ens3
Link 2 (ens3):
root@vm905709:~#
```

(BTW, I did it on the same VPS with Debian and it was the same.)

And Global:

```
root@vm905709:~# resolvectl dns
Global: 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
Link 2 (ens3):
root@vm905709:~#
```

You see, there is nothing after "Link 2 (ens3):", but a WireGuard setup guide says:

> You should receive output like the following:
>
> ```
> Link 2 (eth0): 67.207.67.2 67.207.67.3 2001:4860:4860::8844 2001:4860:4860::8888
> ```

I tried to do the same in my local qemu virtual machine with Ubuntu 22 server for test, and it has showed an IP after "Link 2 (ens3):". So on local virtual machine it works, but on remote server (VPS) it doesn't. Why? And do you have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The guide assumes you have nothing in /etc/resolv.conf and have assigned dns directly to each interface.
Since you only have global dns activated (wich is the case as soon as you have a dns in resolv.conf) you can't have specific dns for each interface.
For the guide just use the dns which are shown when using 'resolvectl dns' without any specific interface behind the command.

Greets JayJay